# RelativeLayout - Scroll down

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

I have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+navigate/RLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ABABAB"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/myid" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/myid"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />.
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/firstRectangle"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:layout_below="@+id/myid" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/hotelinfos"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/myid"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/myid"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/hotelname"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hotelinfos"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/hotelinfos" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/hoteladdress"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hotelname"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/hotelname" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/hotelphone"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hoteladdress"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/hoteladdress" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="#12C"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:clickable="true" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#12C"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:id="@+id/hotelemail"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hotelphone"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/hotelphone"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/picture" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/myid"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"       
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/SecondRectangle"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:layout_below="@+id/firstRectangle" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:id="@+id/bookinginfos"
        android:layout_below="@+id/firstRectangle"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/firstRectangle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/pnr"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bookinginfos"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bookinginfos" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/segmentCode"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pnr"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pnr"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/checkin"
        android:layout_below="@+id/segmentCode"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/segmentCode" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/checkout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkin"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkin" 
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/nights"    
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkout"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkout"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/roomType"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nights"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nights" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/boardBasis"
        android:layout_below="@+id/roomType"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/roomType"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/paxNames"
        android:layout_below="@+id/boardBasis"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/boardBasis" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/thirdRectangle"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:layout_below="@+id/SecondRectangle" >
            <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:id="@+id/forHotel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/SecondRectangle"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/SecondRectangle" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/supplierCode"
        android:layout_below="@+id/forHotel"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/forHotel"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I would like to scroll in this layout because the last part of the relativelayout is not visible!
But i don't know how to do it.
I tried to add a scrollview but i got the error: scrollview can host only one direct child!
Do you have any tips for me?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`ScrollView` expects a single child view and in your layout you have 2 `TextView`.
To make the `ScrollView` work you have to wrap your `TextView` in a ViewGroup like `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`.

**Edited code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+navigate/RLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ABABAB"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
// ... THE REST OF YOUR CODE
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3):

Take this code right over you want the scroll to start:

```
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
```

Then end up with   when you want to stop it.

Answer (score 3):

Since `scrollview` can only have a child, the child can be any `layout`. Be in `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`. So it should be something like this. `<ScrollView>` `<RelativeLayout>` `</RelativeLayout>` `</ScrollView>`

Your code would end up like this

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+navigate/RLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ABABAB"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>

<ScrollView>
android:id="@+navigate/Scrollview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+navigate/RLayout02"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"

>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/hcorpo" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/hcorpo"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />.
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/firstRectangle"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hcorpo" >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/hotelinfos"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hcorpo"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/hcorpo"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/hotelname"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hotelinfos"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/hotelinfos" 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/hoteladdress"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hotelname"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/hotelname" 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/hotelphone"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hoteladdress"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/hoteladdress" 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="#12C"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:clickable="true" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:textColor="#12C"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:id="@+id/hotelemail"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hotelphone"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/hotelphone"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp" />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/picture" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/hcorpo"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"       
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/SecondRectangle"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:layout_below="@+id/firstRectangle" >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:id="@+id/bookinginfos"
    android:layout_below="@+id/firstRectangle"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/firstRectangle"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/pnr"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bookinginfos"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bookinginfos" 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/segmentCode"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pnr"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pnr"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/checkin"
    android:layout_below="@+id/segmentCode"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/segmentCode" 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/checkout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkin"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkin" 
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/nights"    
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkout"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkout"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/roomType"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nights"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nights" 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/boardBasis"
    android:layout_below="@+id/roomType"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/roomType"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/paxNames"
    android:layout_below="@+id/boardBasis"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/boardBasis" 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/thirdRectangle"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:layout_below="@+id/SecondRectangle" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:id="@+id/forHotel"
    android:layout_below="@+id/SecondRectangle"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/SecondRectangle" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/supplierCode"
    android:layout_below="@+id/forHotel"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/forHotel"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your last `RelativeLayout`

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/thirdRectangle"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:layout_below="@+id/SecondRectangle" >
            <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:id="@+id/forHotel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/SecondRectangle"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/SecondRectangle" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/supplierCode"
        android:layout_below="@+id/forHotel"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/forHotel"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Should look like this instead:

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/thirdRectangle"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:layout_below="@+id/SecondRectangle" >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:id="@+id/forHotel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/SecondRectangle"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/SecondRectangle" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/supplierCode"
        android:layout_below="@+id/forHotel"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/forHotel"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```